# Hide comments and posts posted by other user

Tags: posts, comments, users, user-roles

I've created a user with role Contributor, when i logged in as Contributor all the posts and comments are listed in the dashboard. How to disable this? I just want to see the post made by me/specific_user. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a filter to pre_get_posts so that only your posts are listed. Something like this:

```
function my_posts_only( $query ) {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( 'edit.php' != $pagenow || ! $query->is_admin )
        return $query;
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        global $user_ID;
        $query->set( 'author', $user_ID );
    }
    return $query;
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_posts_only' );
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Do you know how to do the same for comment listing?

Comment: Example: I just want to see the comments made for my posts.

Comment: Is there any way to do it? Currently WordPress listing all the comments for all roles, example: contributor.